# Why we can not use "le" in for loop and can use in "if condition"

Tags: perl

I've made this program as a beginner. Need to clarify something!
Why I m not able to use "le" in a for loop given below but I'm able to use it in "if condition". What is the reason behind that. ?

```
print "Type the number upto series should run\n";
my $var;
$var = int<STDIN>;
chomp $var;
my ($i, $t);
my $x = 0;
my $y = 1;

if($var eq 1) {
    print "\nYour Series is : $x\n";
} elsif($var eq 2){
    print "\nYour Series is : $x $y\n";
} elsif($var ge 2) {
    print "Your Series is : $x $y ";
    for($i = 1; $i le $var - 2; $i++) {
        # Why the condition not working when I'm using "le"
        # but it does work when I'm using "<="
        $t = $x + $y;
        $x = $y;
        $y = $t; 
        print "$t ";
    }
    print "\n";
} else {
    print "Error: Enter a valid postive integer\n";
}
```

Comment: Please add `use strict; use warnings;` at the top of (all) your script(s).

Comment: What makes you think that this isn't working? Which behaviour did you expect and what are your actual results?

Comment: I had tried and it was not working as desired. I have got the ans with other comments as well.

Comment: Usually people ask about the numeric comparators first (how come `"foo" <= "bar"` is returning true?!?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are free to use `le` and `<=` as you like. But you should be aware that they are *completely* different operators.

Numeric comparision operators are

```
== !=  < <=  > >= <=>
```

The equivalent string comparision operators are

```
eq ne lt le gt ge cmp
```

Strings and numbers are converted to each other as needed. This means for example that

```
 3 ge 20 # true:  3 is string-greater       than 20
11 le  2 # true: 11 is string-less-or-equal than  2
```

because lexicographic ordering compares character by character. Using the numeric operators when you want to treat the contents of your `$variables` as numbers is therefore preferable and will yield the correct results.

Note that Perl translates between strings and numbers invisibly. It is advisable to `use warnings`, so that you get a helpful message when a string can't represent a number (e.g. `"a"`).

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarifying the things !! :)

Answer (score 2):

The correct answer has been given, that `ge` does string comparison, where for example `11` is considered less than `2`. The solution is to use numerical comparison, `==` and `>=`.

I thought I would help demonstrate the problem you are having. Consider this demonstration of how the default `sort` works:

```
$ perl -le 'print for sort 1 .. 10'
1
10
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

As you can see, it considers `10` lower than `2`, and that is because of string comparison, which is the default mode for `sort`. This is how the default sorting routine looks under the hood:

```
sort { $a cmp $b }
```

`cmp` belongs to the string comparison operators, like `eq`, `le`, and `ge`. These operators are described [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Relational-Operators) (`cmp` is below that).

For the sort routine to do what we expect in the above example, we would have to use a numeric comparison operator, which is the "spaceship operator" `<=>`:

```
sort { $a <=> $b }
```

In your case, you can try out your problem with this one-liner:

```
$ perl -nlwe 'print $_ ge 2 ? "Greater or equal" : "Lesser"'
1
Lesser
2
Greater or equal
3
Greater or equal
11
Lesser
```

Answer (score 1):

When you compare numbers with eq, le, gt..... etc; they first be converted to string. And strings will be checkd for alphabatical order, so "11" will be less then "2" here.

So you should be using ==,<=,>= ...etc when comparing numbers.

Answer (score 1):

I thought you may like to see a more Perl-like program that produces the Fibonnaci series like yours.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

print "Type the length of the series\n";
chomp(my $length = <>);
unless ($length and $length !~ /\D/ and $length > 0) {
  print "Error: Enter a positive integer\n";
}

print "\n";

my @series = (0, 1);
while (@series < $length) {
  push @series, $series[-2] + $series[-1];
}

print "@series[0..$length-1]\n";
```