# What is "-le" in shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am going through [this code](https://github.com/srvk/eesen/blob/master/asr_egs/tedlium/v1/run_ctc_phn.sh). I would like to know what is meant by 
`-le` in the following code segment.

```
if [ $stage -le 2 ]; then
```

In one of the questions it says that `-le` stands for `<=` of strings, but that is in Perl. Is it the same here as well?

Further, I would like to know if that `$stage` variable automatically gets updated. It has been initialized to `0` at the beginning, but later, how does that get incremented?

Comment: less than or equal to?

Comment: These are two separate questions, both of which are covered elsewhere.

Comment: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html explains `test`/`[`

Comment: Is it not the same? I found it [here] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16355910/why-we-can-not-use-le-in-for-loop-and-can-use-in-if-condition)

Comment: google for "man test"

Answer (score 2):

As is stated [in the documentation](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html):

> **integer comparison**
>
> (...)
>
> **`-lt`**: is less than
>
> ```
> if [ "$a" -lt "$b" ]
> ```

So it **interprets** the values of `$a` and `$b` (in your case `$stage` and `2`) as integers and performs a comparison. If the first element is less than or equal to the second, the test succeeds and the `then` part will be executed.

As the documentation later states, one can use `<=` as well:

> **`<=`**: is less than or equal to (within double parentheses)
>
> ```
> (("$a" <= "$b"))
> ```

But then one uses **double parentheses** (as specified in the documentation).

Comment: By the way can you explain whether that $stage value get updated throughout the script? because I can't find how it happens. Or is it that it always 0 unless it's value being updated to some higher value due to some condition occur at some other file?

Comment: @udani: the `if` statement does not update values. Probably somewhere in the file you will find a statement like `stage=$(($stage+1))` which gives it a new value (increment).

Answer (score 2):

`-le` is less than or equals to :

```
if [ $stage -le 2 ];
```

is same as:

```
stage <= 2
```