# need help understanding bash syntax

Tags: bash, while-loop

I am trying to understand bash syntax a bit better, and I need some help with a while loop:

The following script works:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
counter=2
mystring=testdir
while [ $counter -le 5 ]; do
  echo Making dir $mystring$counter
  mkdir $mystring$counter
  ls *.slurm > $mystring$counter/testfile.$counter.slurm
  counter=$((counter+1))
done
```

**Question 1:** what is `-le` ? Google didn't seem to help, showing me any page with the word 'linux' in it

I literally copied the following form the while manual, and it does not work:

```
#!/bin/bash
 set x 0
 while {$x<10} {
 puts "x is $x"
 incr x
}

#test3.sh: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
#test3.sh: line 6: `}'
```

**Question 2:** What am I doing wrong? Thank you for your attention :)

Comment: Please ask one question at a time. If there are two unrelated questions, it is considered off-topic for being too broad.

Comment: The second one looks like Tcl, not Bash.

Comment: Duplicate for first question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34807689/what-is-le-in-shell-script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[` is a synonym for `test` builtin function and `-le` is one of the possible tests, lower or equal. In bash try this for more details:

```
help [
help test
```

Re. your second question, it doesn't look like bash syntax at all.

Comment: Thank you. I went back and checked the ' man whil'e results and it looks like the example is in Tcl language?! I was puzzled because I copied and pasted the example, and it was not working. Still looks confusing to me the way the man page is set up.

Answer (score 2):

> what is `-le` ?

it means "less than or equal".

> What am I doing wrong?

Almost everything. Your script should look like this in bash

```
x=0
while [ $x -lt 10 ]; do
    echo "x is $x"
    ((x++))
done
```

I think you really should read the bash manual.